# Convert list of Boolean functions into logic circuit

Tags: boolean-algebra, boolean

Assume that I have a list of variables $x_1,...,x_n$ and a list of Boolean functions $f_1(x_1,...,x_n),...,f_m(x_1,...,x_n)$

What I would like to do is create a circuit gate graph $G=(V,E)$ which satisfies:

1. if $x\in V$ then there must be one of the following cases:

   - $x\in \{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is variable
   - $x$ is an `and` gate
   - $x$ is an `or` gate
   - $x$ is a `not` gate
2. $E$ is a directed edge set representing the data flow from one node to another
3. For each Boolean expression $f_i(x_1,...,x_n)$ there must be a node $v_i\in V$ based on the data flow and calculation, where $v_i$ and $f_i$ has the same value
4. The graph should have the least nodes possible.

I can simplify a single boolean expression, but with many of them, it becomes complicated. Thus, I would like to ask if there is a proper algorithm to do this??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are your equations in disjonctive normal form ?

Comment: @jeanmarie what do you mean by "disjunctive"....

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form

Comment: OP states the clause can consist of arbitrary `and`, `or`, `not` operators.

Comment: Right but I think Jean Marie is asking because there are algorithms to simplify to DNF so I'm guessing we can assume it

Comment: @jeanmarie not really but the function can be converted into that

Comment: Even when $m=1$, this is NP-hard.

Comment: @justauser it's OK since in my case, the functions will not be very complicated, thus what I need is a proper algorithm that is programmable